# TypeError: str, bytes or bytearray expected, not list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sockets

So I am trying to pull some IP's from a text file and using that list in the socket connection. My issue is I keep getting the following error:

TypeError: str, bytes or bytearray expected, not list

Here is the code im using:

```
    import socket

     ips = open('list.txt', 'r').readlines()

     def displayType(sec_type):
       switcher = {
        0: "1",
        1: "2",
        2: "3"
       } 
       print(' type: ' + str(sec_type) + ' (' + switcher.get(sec_type,"Not defined by IETF") +')' )

    try:
       def check(ip,port):
         link = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
         link.connect((ip,int(port)))
         link_ver = link.recv(12)
         print(link_ver)

         link.send(link_ver)
         nb_sec_types = ord(link.recv(1))
         print("types: " + str(nb_sec_types))

    check(ips,"80")
```

If anyone has an idea on how to use the ip's from the list that would be great.

Comment: The error is pretty intuitive.. which line raises the error?

Comment: sorry about that. its the line that has: check(ips,"5900") & also : link.connect((ip,int(port)))

Comment: the object `ips` Is a list. When you call `link.connect`, you end up passing a `list` as an argument, but it says that `link.connect` expects a string instead. You can fix that by iterating through your list of `ips`, for example: `for ip in ips: check(ip, "80)`

Comment: Awesome thank you for that I made the changes and it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
check(ips, "80)
```

for

```
for ip in ips: 
    check(ip, "80)
```

`link.connect` expected a unique `ip` and you're passing a list of ips.

Answer (score 0):

The method `readlines()` reads until EOF and returns a list containing the lines. So you are getting a list in ips. You will need to iterate over this list and call check() on each iteration.

Also, you have used `try` block without `except` or `finally`. This will result into error.

You can put catch() inside the try-except block as:

```
try:
 catch(ip, port)
except Exception as e:
 print(str(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

You must first convert the string that contains the IP address into a byte or a string of bytes and then start communicating.
According to the code below, your error will be resolved.
Make sure your code is working correctly overall.

```
string = '192.168.1.102'
new_string = bytearray(string,"ascii")
ip_receiver = new_string
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.sendto(text.encode(), (ip_receiver, 5252))
```